# need to extract 10 docs each from 30 users in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

this example is from elastic search official docs

```
GET /_search
{
    "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

which return 10 docs for user "kimchy".

I have 30 more such users, is there any way to extract 10 docs from each of the user in a request.

Currently I hit 30 queries separately and later join all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, You can use **terms** query for multiple users -

```
GET /_search
{
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "abc", "xyz"] }
  }
}
```

Refer this for more details - [Terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Comment: thanks @Surabhi K but it gives a total result of 10 docs combined for these 3 users.  but i need 10 docs from each users, means total 30 docs (10 from each user)

Comment: @sachin You need 30 documents, with these users? Then you change the size to 30.

Comment: I think if i set size 30 then its no gurantee that docs from each user has a exact count 10. I need a query which set exact 10 size to each user